# Can not bypass MAC address filtering

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, router, mac-address

I add a `white list` filter by mistake to my wifi modem router, so I want to change MAC address to that IP. I run this command:

```
ifconfig wlan0 down
ifconfig wlan0 hw ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
ifconfig wlan0 up
```

and

```
sudo macchanger --mac=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx  wlan0
```

My MAC changed successfully, but still I can't connect to the router also after a try to connecting, MAC address automatically back to default. What should I do? I have not access to the router.

Comment: I recommend reseting your router to default settings and setting it up anew. Check manual for your router to find how to do it.

Comment: @Nikolay Thanks, but I have not physical access to the router.

Comment: Is it your router?